# QueryDsl inner join

Tags: java, querydsl

I have been struggling with query dsl joins. My problem is with unidirectional Many to One mapping. I am unable to fetch data from both tables as query dsl is unable to find many to one relationship entity as null. As I am using latest query dsl library and spring data.

```
@Entity
 Public class Parent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
 private Integer id;

 @ManyToOne
 private Child c;

// Getters and setters.
 }

@Entity
public class Child {

@Id
@GenereatedValue
private Integer id;

private String name;

// Getters and setters
 }

// Query dsl method.
public List<Parent>  getParentsByChildName(String name){

 QParent qParent = QParent.parent ;
 QChild qChild = QChild.child;

 return queryFactory.select(Qparent).from(qChild).innerJoin(qParent). where (qChild.name.eq(name));
}
```

Comment: Here's an idea ... think about how you expect anyone to "answer" that without you actually DEFINING your problem, and PROVIDING some code ...

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. Here's some raw code snippet. Please don't mind syntactic mistakes. Due to company policy I can't upload original source anywhere. Any help appreciated.

Comment: My problem is that How should I form an inner join on Parent and Child so I can fetch data from both the tables based on provided criteria which may include parent attributes or child&#39;s attributes or rather combination of them.